# python post requests login into a website

Tags: python, post, python-requests

hey I'm having troubles using post requests to login to a website. Any help would be great.

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
url = 'https://atcbuilder.io/login.php'

data = {"form_username":" shortman443", "form_password":" Owensag2"}
params = {'sessionKey': '9ebbd0b25760557393a43064a92bae539d962103',     'format': 'xml', 'platformId': 1}

r = requests.post(url, params=params, data=json.dumps(data),   headers=headers)

print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About this kind of question you should learn how to use tool,such as `Fiddler`. To catch http response and watch the different between boswer and `requests`.

```
import requests

url = 'https://atcbuilder.io/login.php'
data = {"form_username":"test", "form_password":"test"} #if your pwd and username dont contain space,then dont add it.otherwise you never login successfully
r = requests.post(url, data=data)

print(r.text.find("Logout"))
print(r.text.find("Sign Up"))
```